# Is it possible to prevent Hazelcast from copying and registering MapInterceptors that are registered on other nodes

Tags: hazelcast

When adding second and subsequent node to cluster I am having problems with setting my custom interceptors that implement MapInterceptor interface.
The issue is that, that when it comes to registering my custom interceptors on joining node, Hazelcast has already interceptors registered under specific keys(and actually theses are my custom interceptors, but firstly registered on the first node and then registered on every subsequent node).
The reason for that issue seems to be repartitioning process that is invoked on every new node join which results in copying interceptors through the network from the first node that joined the cluster and registering them before joining node will do it by itself.

Reason for which I want to register new interceptor every time new node join the cluster is that my custom interceptors carry a state that is specific for the node on which I want it to be registered. Currently I made a workaround that will inject overridden state whenever my custom interceptor is used. But if possible it would be great to apply some more efficient and simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [related javadoc](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/MapInterceptor.java#L27) and [ref manual](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#adding-interceptors)? You can implement `hashcode()` method in Interceptor implementation to prevent chaining them.

Comment: Yes, I have seen and followed this advice.
But due to fact that `hashcode()` is constant for particular implementation and because `hashcode()` is taking part in 'interceptor-key' generation process under which particular interceptors are then registered I can't prevent Hazelcast from registering interceptors from first node on joining node under these specific keys. In short: Hazelcast will register interceptors from 1st node on joining node before my joining node will to it for it self(by the time this will happen 'interceptor-keys' are already in use on joining node).

Comment: Since Map Interceptors are registered per-map, it's not correct to hold state of members in the interceptor itself. And it's not possible to make Interceptors local to members, so I'd suggest you to make interceptors stateless and hold member state somewhere else, for example using [Member Attributes](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.9/manual/html-single/index.html#defining-member-attributes) which looks like a fit for your need.

Comment: Mentioned state describes variable in time cluster state which can be controlled by every node in a thread safe manner and must be announced to every node at every change. This state determines how my custom interceptors will work. So unfortunately I can't provide it through Member Attributes.

Comment: I understand that registration concept is unchangeable - 'interceptor-key' remains same for every map regardless of the node.
But maybe there is some way to swap interceptor registration during repartitioning process with interceptor registration during instance creation. This way newly created node could register its interceptors before joining the cluster and before repartitioning process register interceptors from other nodes.

Comment: Seems that no one else tried to use interceptors in that way. Anyway, thanks for trying to help